# Keep video player control text in position

Tags: jquery, css

I have a video player control in JavaScript that I need to keep the time played and time total in place when the user enlarges the video, or makes the screen larger than 1500px wide. Not sure if I should use a media query or append CSS to the jQuery of the text classes, to ensure the text doesn't go out of bounds and overlay the controls when the window is enlarged or shrunk.

jQuery used to control player icons/text

```
    $('document').ready(function () {
    // resize on dom ready
    resizePlayer();

    // add window resize binding
    $(window).resize(resizePlayer);
});

function resizePlayer() {
    var newWidth = $('.timeline').outerHeight() * 0.25;

    var containerSize = $('.timeline').width();
    var textPercentage = 0.57391304347826086956521739130435; /* 40/230 */
    var textRatio = containerSize * textPercentage;
    var textEms = textRatio / 244;

    $('.play, .pause, .mute, .fullscreen').width(newWidth);
    $('.time-played, .timeline, .time-total').css('fontSize', textEms+"em");
}
```

CSS

```
    body {
    background-color: #000;
}
 .video-controls {
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 2147483647;/*has to be here for full screen*/
    /* default min-height */
    height: 12%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    min-width:500px;
  }

  .video-controls .container-fluid {
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -14px;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    width: inherit;
  }

  /* button & button alignments */

  .video-controls .btn {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-indent: 200%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: top;
    outline: 0;
    cursor
  }

  .video-controls .btn-group-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    right: -106px;
    height: 100%;
  }

.play {
    position: absolute;
    left: -73px;
    top:-2px;
    background: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-play-128.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    /* 14 x 19 */
    background-size: 17px 16px;
    width: 14px;
}
.pause {
    position: absolute;
    left: -73px;
    top:-2px;
    background: url(/testPlayer/img/pause.svg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    /* 14 x 19 */
    background-size: 17px 16px;
    width: 14px;
}
.mute {
    background: url(http://iconizer.net/files/Token/orig/Sound.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    right: 55px;
    background-size: 17px 16px;
    /* 26 x 24 */
    width: 26px;
}
.fullscreen {
    background: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface/100/make_bigger_fullscreen_1-512.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    right: 15px;
    background-size: 17px 14px;
    width: 24px;
    /* 24 x 19 */
}
.timeline {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 55%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:#fff;
}
.timeline input {
    margin-top: -1px;
}
.timeline .time-total {
    position: absolute;
    top: 39%;
    right: -47px;
    font-size:14px;
    color: #000;
}
.timeline .time-played {
    position: absolute;
    top: 39%;
    left: -37px;
    font-size:14px;
    color: #000;
}
.timeline-progress, .timeline-total {
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
}
.timeline-total {
    width: 100%;
    /*background: rgba(255,255,255,.22);*/
    z-index: 1;
}
.timeline-progress {
    width: 24%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Here's a fiddle for example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/zq2vzkk5/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the font size proportionately with this js:

```
$('.time-played, .timeline, .time-total').css('fontSize', textEms+"em");
```

But the containing  is not changing its size or position.  If you remove this line of code, you will see the times stay in position but do not change size.  If changing the font size with this script is critical, you will need to adjust the position of the div's as well.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zq2vzkk5/4/

Comment: This seems to work well enough for the left side, but I still have the total count(right side) overlapping the controls in my view(the fiddle works just fine)